# Unit testing method with async

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I am writing a unit test for a method using `Moq` framework.

The method calls the method `Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)` of `System.Net.Http` with `await`.

When I execute my test case the method does not return anything. Certainly, I am doing something wrong. Please help me to find it.

Please note that this call is not loosely coupled.

I did check the other answers like [Unit testing async method - test never completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365479/unit-testing-async-method-test-never-completes) which have it as loosely coupled and could be mocked.

**Edit 1**: 
The method similar to which I am trying to unit test

```
class Class1
    {
        public async Task<string> Method(string url)
        {

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,url);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await new HttpClient().SendAsync(request);
            return System.Convert.ToString( response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your unit test code to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to mock the `HttpClient`?  If so this isn't the recommended approach; instead of mocking `HttpClient` instantiate a real `HttpClient`, passing a mocked `HttpMessageHandler` into the constructor.

Source: https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/

Edit: to read the contents of a HTTP response you need to call the `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` method instead of `.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to a new concept. In my case constructor of the class itself creates a class. So this does not seems working for me. But thanks again to introducing to this.

Comment: Add your code to your post and people will be in a better position to help you.